# Trigger.io App crashing when using forge.event.connectionStateChange.addListener

Tags: trigger.io

I'm trying to use `forge.event.connectionStateChange.addListener` from the [docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/event.html#connectionstatechange-addlistener). I've create and entirely empty application, added `"event":true` to the `config.json` configuration and added the following bit to the `main.js`:

```
forge.logging.info("Add JavaScript to js/main.js!");

forge.event.connectionStateChange.addListener(
    function() {
      alert('Device ' + (forge.is.connection.connect() ? "is" : "is not") + 'connected.');
    },
    function(){
      alert('Erorr');
    }
);
```

When I run the application and turn off my machine's wifi, the application crashes. I can provide more log if needed.

```
[DEBUG] Native call: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "9B3DBB44-870E-438B-8128-07E88474DDAB";
[DEBUG]     method = "launchimage.hide";
[DEBUG]     params =     {
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG] }
[DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
[DEBUG]     callid = "9B3DBB44-870E-438B-8128-07E88474DDAB";
[DEBUG]     content = "<null>";
[DEBUG]     status = success;
[DEBUG] }
[INFO] No reload update available.
[INFO] 2013-03-04 16:59:54.725 Forge[68603:c07] +[BorderControl returnResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2fb4a4
[INFO] 2013-03-04 16:59:54.725 Forge[68603:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[BorderControl returnResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2fb4a4'
[INFO] *** First throw call stack:
[INFO] (0x33b6012 0x2e55e7e 0x34412ad 0x33a5bbc 0x33a594e 0x2e695c8 0x2895765 0x3339f3f 0x333996f 0x335c734 0x335bf44 0x335be1b 0x33107e3 0x3310668 0x1d99ffc 0x26e6 0x2625)
[INFO] libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Also, I do not get an alert on app startup as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I'm not even using a listener.  Mine just crashes in the background when I switch to wifi on my iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1

Comment: @JohnClarkeMills You're right. When I drop my listener, and just use a newly created project, I see the same crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry - our bad: this is a symptom of the same problem which was causing problems with Reload in v1.4.32.

There's a fix in v1.4.33 - please do give it a try and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It looks like v1.4.33 allows us to turn off the wifi. We are seeing our Pusher channel disconnect and reconnect when wifi returns without the app crashing. Thanks!